# Error when using firebase serverTimestamp() in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am trying to use firebase serverTimestamp with nodejs

```
const Queue = require('firebase-queue');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { Firestore } = require('@google-cloud/firestore');

const firestore = new Firestore();

    job.ref.update({
     timeProcessingEnded: admin.firestore().FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
   })
```

Also tried:

```
admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),

firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
```

I get an error

> Cannot read property 'serverTimestamp' of undefined

Comment: It's really not a good idea to mix `@google-cloud/firestore` with `firebase-admin`.  The Admin SDK is just a wrapper around the google cloud SDK. If you want to use firebase-admin, you should just use its exported APIs exclusively, ignoring the exports from google cloud.  This means you should follow the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to initialize the Admin SDK.  Also note in that documentation they are showing you different imports that what you're using now.

Comment: It's `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`, so without parenthesis after `firestore`.